# Keeping distance attribute with user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

If I have a User model, in which I have a distance attribute which I don't want to save to the database but to use it for the SQL query which calculates the distance as something that will hold the value returned by the query.

So it's declared like this in my model (**there is no distance column in the database**) :

```
attr_accessor :distance
```

But when I do something like :

```
User.where('...').select('222 as distance, id')
```

Example output would be :

```
#<User id: 12631>
```

So why is rails not injecting the `distance` returned by the query in my model? and how can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr_accessor` sets up getters and setters for the instance variable `@distance`, not the active record attribute.

If you remove the attr_accessor you can access the selected column as you would any other attribute.

```
  User.select('222 as distance, id').each { |u| puts "#{u.id}, #{u.distance}" }
  // 1, 222
  // 2, 222 ....
```

Comment: this doesn't work, because the distance is not in the database, the result is the same as before. thanks

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow: Have you actually tried this? The `inspect` output (i.e. `#<User id: 12631>`) only displays things that the model knows about (i.e. database columns) but that doesn't mean that `user.distance` won't work.

Comment: @muistooshort yes I have tried it here is the output :
`User Load (33.0ms)  SELECT 222 as distance, id FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 19016 AND ("users".deleted_at IS NULL)
19016,`